# ThreadLocal initialization

Tags: java, initialization, thread-local

Every example of ThreadLocal I've seen returns a value which can't be set dynamically, like this example with the SimpleDateFormat, which always returns the same SimpleDateFormat every time:

```
public class Foo
{
    // SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe, so give one to each thread
    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>(){
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue()
        {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");
        }
    };

    public String formatIt(Date date)
    {
        return formatter.get().format(date);
    }
}
```

But lets say that I want to be able to configure what value is returned. One way would be to use system properties like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    // SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe, so give one to each thread
    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>(){
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue()
        {
            String dateFormat = System.getProperty("date.format");
            return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        }
    };

    public String formatIt(Date date)
    {
        return formatter.get().format(date);
    }
}
```

But what if I don't want to use system properties but rather want to supply the class with the necessary information at the time it is created. How do I do that. Everything is static so I can't use a constructor.

The reasons I don't like the system property approach is many. For one I don't want the class to know stuff about its surroundings like that there is a system property that is should read. It should be as simple as possible and get all its dependencies injected. I think that way of coding improves testability for example.

**Final solution**

The format is set once by calling setFormat and all calls to formatIt uses the same format after that.

```
public class Foo {

    private static volatile String FORMAT;

    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Set the format. Must be called before {@link #formatIt(Date)}. Must only be called once.
     * 
     * @param format
     *            a format, e.g. "yyyyMMdd HHmm".
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *             if this method has already been called.
     */
    public static void setFormat(String format) {
        if (Foo.FORMAT != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Format has already been set");
        }
        FORMAT = format;
    }

    /**
     * @return the formatted date.
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *             if this method is called before {@link #setFormat(String)} has been called.
     */
    public static String formatIt(Date date) {
        if (Foo.FORMAT == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Format has not been set");
        }
        return formatter.get().format(date);
    }

}
```

Comment: do you use java 8?

Comment: No, I use Java 1.6.

Comment: Wy the down vote? I have researched this extensively and I am an experienced programmer. It's not like I'm in school and just want you guys to help me with a assignment. This will be used in production. If the one who gave me the down vote think it's a trivial question please provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't use a DI framework, for me the only way is to add a `static` setter allowing to change dynamically your format, something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private static volatile String FORMAT = "yyyyMMdd HHmm";

    // SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe, so give one to each thread
    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = 
        new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>(){
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);
        }
    };

    public static void setFormat(String format) {
        FORMAT = format;
    }
    ...
}
```

It is quite ugly but I don't see any better approach.

---

In this particular use case, as you use Java 6, I would clearly recommend to use [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) of [**Joda-Time**](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of `SimpleDateFormat` as it does the same thing and it is thread safe out of the box.

**Here is how your code would look like:**

```
public class Foo {

    private static volatile DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmm");;

    public String formatIt(Date date) {
        return formatter.print(date.getTime());
    }

    public static void setFormat(String format) {
        formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
    }
}
```

As you can see the `ThreadLocal` is no more needed as `DateTimeFormatter` is thread-safe.

**NB:** I assumed that you need to set the format **globally** for all instances of `Foo`, if it is not the case, you should rather use this:

```
public class Foo {

    private volatile DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmm");;

    public String formatIt(Date date) {
        return formatter.print(date.getTime());
    }

    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
    }
}
```

With this approach you inject the format which is a much more OO approach.

Comment: This is actually a lot simpler, I shouldn't be thinking about threadlocals when I'm tired.

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you for the suggested solution. However, does this solution differ from the solution previously propposed by Kayaman?

Comment: Which one? he proposed 2 solutions

Comment: The "ugly" one :) The difference between that solution and this one seems to be you using the volatile keyword and him having some checks that the FORMAT variable is actually set when you call get() the first time. I was just wondering what made him remove his solution and say this is simpler. They seem pretty much equal to me.

Comment: the singleton is not lazily created which is much less error prone and simpler

Comment: I set a default value for the format to avoid having to check if it is set or not

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have posted my final solution in my original question. By the way, that is not the actual code. I am not using this for SimpleDateFormat but for something else. I just used this example because it is simple enough to discuss.

Comment: good news FORMAT should be volatile or an AtomicReference for thread safety

Comment: Thanks for telling me that FORMAT should be volatile. I read up on volatile and understand why now. Thanks!